# curl: error while loading shared libraries: libnettle.so.6

Tags: ubuntu, kernel, apt, curl, wget

I have reached to my server and i have tried to perform and `apt-get update` but i get an issue related with libnettle.so.6 so i'm not able to do `apt-get remove libnettle6` because i get exactly the same issue so i searched a bit on google about this issue and i found somewhere on stacoverflow than someone get the same issue but fixed when installed with `dpkg -i` but he does a `curl` or a `wget` command but i not able becuase i get this error

*Curl*

```
curl: error while loading shared libraries: libnettle.so.6 ...
```

*wget*

```
resolving google.com(Google.com) ... failed: temporary failure in name resolution . 
wget: ubable to resolve host address ' google.com'
```

so there is someone here can help me to know how can i fix this .

I also tried to run in secure kernel mod but same issue no internet connection

No ssh connection i can perform unfortunately

Kind regards

Comment: Diagnose your internet connection first. `libnettle` thing and no internet connection thing are two separate issues.

Comment: I have checked and in rescue mode provided and made by my web hosting company it works well, BTW the ping also gives me a issue related with `libnettle6`

Comment: Do you have any experience with unix / linux systems at all? If not it might be better to ask for help somebody with minimal experience. Your suggestion about removing libnettle only shows that you might already damaged your system blindly doing "things" from all over Internet :(

Comment: I'm using Linux over 4 years, but I thought than removing libnettle6 and reinstall them it again it would be fix it.  I never experienced this issue in 4 years so don't know what to do, and the web hosting provider can't help me cuz they don't do software support, and I don't know why the libnettle6 as been corrupted. It happens without touching nothing I just tried to do a `apt update ` and it have happened `libnettle6 error `

Comment: It seems that it is remote machine so you've got access to it via internet. Check your /etc/resolv.conf file so proper dns addresses are there and we will get rid of "cant resolve" problem first

Comment: Looks like there is a tons of files and folders missing on `/run/` because the i looked at the symlink and it point to `/run/systemd... ` btw I'm under rescue mod not sure if it interfere with it but I think no.

Comment: If you are desperate enough, then try locating `libnettle.so.6` file and copy this library to your lib directory or wherever it should be. Try properly chrooting into your system from rescue mode and find out whether it is working properly and what else is missing.